# How to read an xml file directly to get an XElement value?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader, xelement

Right now I am using:

```
XElement xe = XElement.ReadFrom
```

which requires an `XmlReader`:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create
```

which requires a string, and that requires me to pass a `StringReader`:

```
new StringReader
```

which requires a `TextReader/StreamReader` to finally be able to pass the file path to it:

```
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader ( file );
```

Is the simpliest way to do this? I already have code that uses an `XElement` so it works fine but I want to cut down the number of steps to get the `XElement` from an xml file. Something like:

```
XElement xe = XElement.ReadFrom (string file);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Joan, use [XDocument.Load(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx):

> XDocument doc =
>   XDocument.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");

Some comments:

1. You should never use `XmlTextReader.Create`. use `XmlReader.Create`. It's a static method, so it doesn't make a difference which derived class you use to refer to it. It's misleading to use `XmlTextReader.Create`, since it looks like that's different from `XmlReader.Create`. It's not.
2. `XmlReader.Create` has an overload that accepts a string, just like `XDocument.Load` does: [`XmlReader.Create(string inputUri)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf.aspx).
3. There's actually no such thing as `XElement.ReadFrom`. It's actually [`XNode.ReadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx).

Comment: Thanks John, but if I do that, can I still do xe.Elements("something").Elements("else").Select, etc?

Comment: Joan, yes. There's no such thing as `XElement.Elements`. It's [`XContainer.Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx). I strongly suggest you start noticing which class things are defined in. Many are inherited.

Comment: Thanks John, so do static methods get carried to all derived types? Also you said XmlReader.Create takes a string, but that's not a file path (to read the file contents), right? Lastly I now saw that XElement.ReadFrom is XNode.ReadFrom, but in that case, how does it appear under XElement? Same inheritance deal?

Comment: @Joan: yes, statics are always inherited (assuming they're not `private`). The `XmlReader.Create` overload that takes a string treats it as a URI, but "filename.typ" is treated just like a file path. Yes, same inheritance deal.

Comment: Thanks, then in that case, should I use XDocument.Load or XmlReader.Create for the file path as a best practice?

Comment: @Joan: it doesn't matter. `XDocument.Load(string)` almost certainly calls `using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(string)) {return XDocument.Load(reader);}`. In other words, _everything_ eventually comes down to an `XmlReader`.

Comment: Thanks John, appreciate your help. My code now works good and is more elegant too.

Answer (score 4):

```
XElement.ReadFrom(XmlReader.Create(fileName))
```

But explicitly managing file stream objects and XmlReader objects is better - you know when streams are closed...

Comment: So if you do this, the reader and stream objects will leak memory?

Comment: @Joan: no, they don't leak resources (they never leak memory under any circumstances) - it's just that the resources won't get cleaned up until the garbage collector eventually gets around to it.

Comment: If you're concerned about releasing resources, as a good programmer should be, you can wrap your code in a using statement since XmlReader implements IDisposable: `using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("SomeFile.xml")) { var element = XElement.ReadFrom(reader); }`